# how to create worker nodes in private subnet in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created EKS cluster. VPC which is part of EKS has 4 subnets . 2 public subnets and 2 private subnets .
Added the worker node groups as well which has 3 nodes.

Now , the issue is all these worker nodes are deployed in public subnets. However, I want atleast one node in private subnet .

Please suggest that , how to deploy worker node in private subnet through EKS management console

Comment: please suggest . not able to understand on this

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide to create managed nodegroup
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-managed-node-group.html

Specify the private subnets while configuring the Networking as mentioned in Point no. 8.

Comment: I have gone through this page earlier as well. The issue is , I dont have option to select which node should be placed in which subnet. for example, in one node group, if im creating 4 nodes , out of which I need 2 nodes in one public subnet and 2 nodes in one private subnets , then I dont find such option.  AWS itself decides how to place these nodes in which subnets  . please suggest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are using AWS managed or self managed nodegroups?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy to a private subnet (private_node_group), you can use **labels**. follow my code below:

Terraform to create private_node_group:

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "private-nodes" {
  cluster_name    = "cluster_name"
  node_group_name = "private-nodes"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.nodes.arn
  subnet_ids      = [private_subnet_id_1, private_subnet_id_2]
  labels = {
    nodegroup = "private"
  }
}
```

.yaml file to deploy k8s. in values.yaml file:

```
nodeSelector: {
  nodegroup: private
}
```

template/deployment.yaml file:

```
spec:
 template:
   spec:
     [...]
     nodeSelector:
       nodegroup: {{ .Values.nodeSelector.nodegroup }}
```